# PHP - Laravel - Enviar um dado inserido no banco para outra view

Tags: php, html5, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Ja li questões a respeito sobre isso, mas ainda não consegui resolver meu problema.

é o seguinte, tenho uma view no Laravel separada para cadastrar usuário. Ai na teoria devia redirecionar para uma outra view onde fornecerá outros dados do usuario. Porém não estou conseguindo enviar o id dessa inserção da primeira view para a segunda e fazer a relação entre elas.
Eis o controller user a função onde inseria no banco e depois retornaria pra outra view

```
public function store(Request $request, User $user) {
    $dataform = $request->except('_token');
    $insert = $user->insert($dataform);
    if ($insert) {
        return view('instrutor',compact('dataform')); //Queria que enviasse somente o ID.
    } else {
        return redirect()->back();
    }  
}
```

E aqui a função do controller onde deveria receber o ID e inserir na tabela instrutor os dados do formulario e anexar o id do usuario.

```
    public function store(Request $request, Instrutor $instrutor) {
    //
    $dataform = $request->except('_token');
    $insert = $instrutor->insert($dataform);
    if ($instrutor) {
        return redirect()->route('index');
    } else {
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

São duas tabelas diferentes users e instrutor, onde instrutor esta relacionada a usuers com chave estrangeira

Answer (score 1):

Você pode obter o ID após a inserção, então seu método ficaria algo como:

```
public function store(Request $request, Instrutor $instrutor) {
  //
  $dataform = $request->except('_token');
  $insert = $instrutor->insert($dataform);
  if ($instrutor) {
      return redirect()->route('index')->with('minha_id' => $insert->id);
  } else {
      return redirect()->back();
  }
}
```

Outra abordagem (a qual eu prefiro) é no lugar de você dar um redirect, dar um return view direto.

No lugar de:

```
return redirect()->route('index')->with('minha_id' => $insert->id);
```

Eu coloco:

```
return view('index', ['minha_id' => $insert->id]);
```

Assim o meu método `store` além de inserir os primeiros dados no banco, já renderizam a próxima tela, me poupando de ter que criar um novo método apenas para apresentar esta tela. Se você precisar de algum dado cadastrado, pode passar o model, recém inserido, inteiro para a nova view.

```
return view('index', ['model' => $insert]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode redirecionar passando esta ID como uma variável através do método with();
Ex.: `return redirect()->route('index')->with('variavel' => 'valor');`

Comment: Ola @cleber-martins, interessante sua ideia mas como pegarei especificamente o o campo id do $dataform?

Comment: Desculpe, devo ter entendido errado. Vc quer então recuperar o ID inserido na tabela User para então na tabela Instrutor.

Comment: Tipo, cadastrei o usuario
email e senha
enviei pro banco agora redireciona pra tela de Instrutor
preciso desse id do usuario cadastrado anteriormente para vincula-lo ao instrutor.